# How to check whether a buffer is visiting a file?

Tags: elisp, buffers, files

I'd like to check whether some (say, current) buffer is visiting a file or not.  I could say:

```
(if (buffer-file-name) ...)
```

but it seems to be not very elegant - what I'm interested in is only the boolean value, not the actual *name* of the buffer in question.  If the `buffer-file-name` function were written in Elisp, I could look into its source to find out what it uses - but it is written in C, and while I could install the Emacs sources, I'm afraid that I wouldn't find an elisp name for the function that checks what I'm after there anyway.

What I need it for is I want to create a directory based on the name of the current buffer's file, and currently I'm doing more or less this:

```
(make-directory (if (buffer-file-name) (file-name-base) "default-dir"))
```

So, what would be the Elisp-idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure why you object to using `buffer-file-name` really, it's the right way to do it (if you really really want `t`, do ``(and (buffer-file-name) t)`` but that's uglier IMO). Its implementation is reading the `filename` field of the buffer C struct, which is anyway not accessible directly from Elisp. In the end, it's just a pointer that is either null or not.

Comment: Well, if this is the right way, that's fine with me.  As I said - I did not know the C implementation, and common sense says that asking for the filename when I only want to know whether there is any might be redundant.

Comment: And I agree that `(and (buffer-file-name) t)` looks strange.

Comment: If you don't think that `(if (buffer-file-name) ... )` is elegant, then you haven't been coding in elisp for very long. It only gets uglier from here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd argue that your usage **is** idiomatic elisp, since the buffer's name is a perfectly appropriate boolean value in its own right.  Quoting from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Truth-_0026-Falsehood.html):

> There is an important aspect to the truth test in an if expression. So far, we have spoken of `true' and `false' as values of predicates as if they were new kinds of Emacs Lisp objects. In fact, `false' is just our old friend `nil`. Anything else—anything at all—is `true'.

To further the point, check out the code for `clone-buffer`.  I expect you'll see the following:

```
(interactive
 (progn
   (if buffer-file-name
       (error "Cannot clone a file-visiting buffer"))
...
```

Note that this is testing the variable binding of `buffer-file-name` instead of calling the function without argument, `(buffer-file-name)`, but the two should always behave the same.

Answer (score 9):

You can use either `(buffer-file-name)` (with optional buffer argument) or the buffer-local `buffer-file-name` variable. Both evaluate to the same value for a given buffer.

That *is* the idiomatic way to do this in Elisp, though, so your code is fine. If you desperately wanted to you could always make a `buffer-has-file-p` wrapper function.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any significant difference to choose the function or the variable?

Comment: I don't think so. If you need to indicate the buffer argument then `(buffer-file-name BUFFER)` is certainly nicer than `(with-current-buffer BUFFER buffer-file-name)`, but otherwise I don't think it matters which one you use (and as function is written in C, I doubt there's even much difference in performance).

Answer (score 3):

Just use `buffer-file-name`.  In Lisp we often use a non-`nil` value to mean **true**.

The only times you might want to avoid this is if the function is costly or has unwanted side effects.

Comment: I see.  I know that anything non-`nil` is true, I just thought grabbing the name when I only want to know whether *any* name exists is "costly" - but seemingly it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

From [the "Buffer List" chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html) of the documentation :

> The list returned by buffer-list is constructed specifically; **it is not an internal Emacs data structure**, and modifying it has no effect on the order of buffers.

So you have to find a way to search in the list of live buffers. Here's one:

```
  (if (string-match-p (regexp-quote "My buffer name") (format "%s" (buffer-list)))
      (message "Open")
    (message "Not open"))
```

Comment: The sexp that is suggested in this answer (as of the time of this writing) might raise some false positives. It checks that `My buffer name` is mentioned in some buffer. A buffer could be named `main.txt - My buffer name` and this will yield true, even though the file with name `My buffer name` is not opened. See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29004) for a solution that I consider better.