# How to check, if a file is already visited?

Tags: buffers, find-file

I have the following code, which opens a file, inserts some text, saves the file and closes it.

```
(defun batch (file)
  (find-file file)
  (end-of-buffer)
  (insert "nix")
  (save-buffer)
  (kill-buffer))
```

If the file is already visited the buffer gets closed. How to prevent that? How to keep the buffer, if `find-file` does not created a new buffer? How to know, if a file has already been opened in a buffer?

Comment: What should be the behavior if the buffer's content is different from the file's content?

Comment: The buffer should be used. The function should not revert.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(get-file-buffer filename)` returns the buffer visiting `filename`, or `nil` if there is none.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html

Edit: [justbur](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14114/justbur) proposes using `(find-buffer-visiting file)` instead, as it also works when the buffer has a different name than the file.

So one solution would be sth in the lines of

```
(defun batch (file)
  (let ((keep (find-buffer-visiting file)))
    (find-file file)
    (end-of-buffer)
    (insert "nix")
    (save-buffer)
    (unless keep (kill-buffer)))
```

but there may be more elegant solutions.